# BI-Publisher RTF Template: Repeat colums or rows horizontally first before new page

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a table that's 2x2. First row is just the header. The second row is pulling info from DB.
The first column is [For-each loop and getting Account number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjWaT.png)
The second column is [getting Balance for that account then ending for-each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIrcw.png)

There are so many account that it goes for many many pages. I want the 2 columns to repeat to the right when it reaches the end of the page. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g46zO.png)

Also the xml structure looks like this.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<reportname>
<LIST_G_1>
    <G_1>
        <ACCOUNT>0</ACCOUNT>
        <BALANCE>0</BALANCE>
        <Q_count>0</Q_count>
        <Q_balance>0</Q_balance>
        <M_count>0</M_count>
        <M_balance>0</M_balance>
        <FS_count>0</FS_count>
        <FS_balance>0</FS_balance>
        <FN_count>0</FN_count>
        <FN_balance>0</FN_balance>
    </G_1>
    <G_1>
        <ACCOUNT>1</ACCOUNT>
        <BALANCE>-250</BALANCE>
        <Q_count>1</Q_count>
        <Q_balance>-250</Q_balance>
        <M_count>0</M_count>
        <M_balance>0</M_balance>
        <FS_count>0</FS_count>
        <FS_balance>0</FS_balance>
        <FN_count>0</FN_count>
        <FN_balance>0</FN_balance>
    </G_1>

</LIST_G_1>
</reportname>
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to make them go horizontal first, like in the picture belew:
[second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5O2P.png)

And if that's not possible, is there a way to do it like the following picture but having the secpnd FE_Acct shows the next-in-line Account number and same with balance, and so on.
[third example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHdP5.png)

I have tried the tag  and it listed all account numbers in the same cell... [inlines issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osYuY.png)

I tried to use    for account, and      for Balance, but they never worked.

Any input is very appreciated since it seems I've hit a wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use multiple Layout-Columns feature of MS Word. Managed to get it with steps as described in the picture.   Added a few more rows to your xml and made data row bigger to test if columns feature works and it seems it does.
[image]

1. repeating for-each LIST_G_1
2. ctrl+A (select all) - Layout - Columns - two (or more)
3. split for-each start and END and draw a table 2x2 in between - put labels and make the 1st row to be repeat as header
4. repeating for-each G_1 in the second row
5. insert fields and define the row height (if needed) to fit your page size
6. run as PDF - you should get something like in the picture

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much!! Your answer just saved me. I had no idea what to do, I was about to rewrite the whole sql and use pivot tables (I don't even know if that would have worked). I did it slightly different than you, but that Layout-->Columns setting is exactly what I was looking for. I seriously cannot thank you enough.